# Error: Permission 'iam.serviceaccounts.actAs' denied on service account (Deploying to Cloud Run with a custom)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to deploy my Docker container to the cloud using GitHub actions.

I have assigned Cloud Run Admin and Artefact Registry Admin to my service account. I have also added Service Account User permission.

Command used for authentication:

```
name: Docker Auth
        id: docker-auth
        uses: "docker/login-action@v3"
        with:
          username: "_json_key"
          password: "${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"
          registry: "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev"
```

Command used for building and pushing Docker images:

```
name: Build and Push Container
        run: |-
          docker build --quiet --build-arg GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }} -t "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.GAR_NAME }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}" ./
          docker push "${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.GAR_NAME }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}"
```

Command used to deploy on Cloud Run:

```
 name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        id: deploy
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v2
        with:
          service: "${{ env.SERVICE }}-${{ env.ENVIRONMENT }}"
          region: ${{ env.REGION }}
          image: ${{ env.GAR_LOCATION }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.GAR_NAME }}/${{ env.SERVICE }}:${{ github.sha }}
          platform: managed
          allow-unauthenticated: true
```

Are there any other permissions or configurations that I'm missing?

Comment: Refer to the similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557008/) for more details.

Comment: I have seen them and assigned permissions according to that, but it was not working earlier. Strange!

Comment: Your feedback on the provided solution is valuable.Please Upvote and accept if it helped; I am here for further assistance if needed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks  that you have configured the necessary permissions for deploying your Docker container to Cloud Run using GitHub Actions.

However, there are a few additional considerations to ensure a successful deployment. To deploy containers to Google Cloud Run using a new service account that you have created with the necessary [Deployment permissions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration) to do deployments.

As per this [blog](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/deploying-to-cloud-run-with-a-custom-service-account-failed-with-iam-serviceaccounts-actas-error/) by ITECNOTE

> **A user needs the following permissions to deploy new Cloud Run services.**
>
> - run.services.create and run.services.update on the project level. Typically assigned through the roles/run.admin role. It can be changed
>   in the project permissions admin page.
> - iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for the Cloud Run runtime service account. By default, this is
>   PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com.
>   The permission is typically assigned through the
>   roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role.

The most important one. You can see here that in order to use non-[default services identities](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity?hl=en#permissions_required_to_use_non-default_identities), the account or deployer needs to have the **iam.serviceAccounts.actAs permission** on the service account that is being deployed.

Refer to this official [Continuous deployment from Git using Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment#continuous) for more information.

**Note** : Depending on usage, certain projects may be restricted to only use Cloud Build in the following regions, check [Restricted regions for some projects](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/locations#restricted_regions_for_some_projects) For more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have resolved this by reassigning service account user permission to my service account.  strangely, it's not working earlier though it has user permission for the service account. Maybe something was missing, but who cares now it's running.